# Problem with Javasript setting an image via src with a variable

Tags: javascript, image, src

I'm trying to set an image to a html element with src. The image is a spotify album cover of which I get the link from spotify (the link looks like this: https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02015c484a7aca592df1a77828)

This is my code:

```
const getSongData = () => {
    currentlyPlaying= localStorage.getItem("currentlyPlaying");
    songDuration = localStorage.getItem("songDuration");
    currentAlbum = localStorage.getItem("currentAlbum");
    currentArtist = localStorage.getItem("currentArtist");
    currentAlbumCover = localStorage.getItem("currentAlbumCover");

    document.getElementById('currentlyPlaying').innerHTML = currentlyPlaying;
    document.getElementById('songDuration').innerHTML = (`${(songDuration/1000)/60}:${(songDuration/1000)%60}`);
    document.getElementById('currentAlbum').innerHTML = currentAlbum;
    document.getElementById('currentArtist').innerHTML = currentArtist;
    document.getElementById('currentAlbumCover').src = currentAlbumCover;
    //console.log(currentAlbumCover);
}
```

So the variable `currentAlbumCover` contains the link and this doesn't work I get this error message:

[image]

The funny thing is it works just fine if I put the link in directly like this:

```
document.getElementById('currentAlbumCover').src = 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02015c484a7aca592df1a77828';
```

Comment: Yeah, but what is the `currentAlbumCover`?
Judging by your error, there's something wrong with the link, because it looks like the src got your local URL prefix somehow.

Comment: Where are you assigning the value to `currentAlbumCover `?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the value of `currentAlbumCover` after `currentAlbumCover = localStorage.getItem("currentAlbumCover");` ?

Comment: You can see there is a `/` at the start of your variable. So that is your problem. The `/` is making it a relative path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error!
The string that I got from Spotify starta and ends with a quote and I didn't notice that in the console...
This line fixes it:

```
currentAlbumCover = localStorage.getItem("currentAlbumCover").replace(/\"/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting shows 404 not found.

This is because `http://localhost:5500` is being added before the link you want.

You're ending up with 
`http://localhost:5500/https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02015c484a7aca592df1a77828`

when you just want `https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02015c484a7aca592df1a77828`

I suspect `localStorage.getItem("currentAlbumCover")` is returning the concatinated value so maybe worth checking how you're saving the value to localStorage.

Comment: I get the image link with a GET request from spotify. the code looks like this: `
  fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${uri}, {
    method: 'GET'
  }).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
    currentAlbumCover = JSON.stringify(data.album.images[1].url);
    console.log(currentAlbumCover);
    reloadSongData();
  });
}` and in reloadSongData() I jsut set the variable to  local storage: `localStorage.setItem("currentAlbumCover", currentAlbumCover);`

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping your variable in the console it looks like you have an an absolute URL being used as a relative path.

If my thought is correct this will dump:
`/https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02015c484a7aca592df1a77828`

So there might be a '/' in front of `currentAlbumCover`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: no thats not the case. When I log the variable to the console it is exactly that link: `https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02015c484a7aca592df1a77828` But when I copy that link and paste it in place of the variable it works...